# Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation while adding inlines to paragraph

Tags: c#, wpf

> An exception of type 'System.ArithmeticException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

```
  public FlowDocument GetFlowDocument(IEnumerable<Item> monitoredItems)
    {
        var document = new FlowDocument();

        var paragraph = new Paragraph();
        var inlines = new List<Inline>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var result = ConvertToInlines(item);
            inlines.AddRange(result);
        }

        paragraph.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
        document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

        return document;
    }
```

exception is being thrown in line:

```
paragraph.Inlines.AddRange(inlines);
```

Adding dispatcher did not help.

Moreover above exception is thrown while invoked in another thread:

```
 Task.Run(() => ...);
```

Comment: Do you have first chance exceptions turned on in VS?

Comment: I do not know, how can I check it?

Comment: if first chance is related to debug then even in release i got "Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation" exception, therefore I assume that it is not the case

Comment: following change helped: I removed Task.Run and used Dispatcher.BeginInvoke instead - till now none exception observed.

Comment: Then the exception that's being thrown isn't really what's happening. Perhaps there's an inner exception?